# In navigation controler how to implement a add button opens a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to swift , I have a very simple question. I implement a navigation controller with two items at top like this 
[image]

I did this by adding a navigation controller to the project and then adding this lines of code in to the viewDidLoad

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = ""
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: Selector(("barButtonItemClicked:"))), animated: true)
  }
```

now my question is about how to open a new view controller I mean a new page after clicks on plus (+) button at the navigation bar. I searched a lot but did not find any exact thing relate to this. Appreciate you if possible help me. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for Push TO OTherView Controller

```
@objc func PoushTOHistoryVC() {

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HistoryViewController") as! HistoryViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

here is Button for Add

```
 self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(PoushTOHistoryVC)), animated: true)
```

you need to add **HistoryViewControlle** to Stroyboard ViewController HistoryViewControlle and Don't forget [image: to tick]

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this one:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(performToVC))

@objc func performToVC() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "vc", sender: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create new view controller which you have to open on that plus (+) button at the navigation bar. After creating new view controller you have to press and hold the control key on the keyboard and the click on the (+) button at the navigation bar and drag it to the new view controller and then release the click button [image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fUbe.png), then it will show you a pop up with options such as show, show details etc[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI3yf.png), select show option.